# What does marginalising out means?

Tags: probability, terminology, marginal-distribution

I am reading an article and it says the following and I quote:

> In particular, if we define SNP-heritability h as the proportion of variance explained by the SNPs included in the model after marginalizing out B, then it is simple to show that
> $$h_g^2 = \operatorname{Var}(\sum_jx_j\beta_j)/\operatorname{Var}(y) = \sum_j \operatorname{Var}(\beta_j)\text{.}$$

Could someone tell me what does marginalising out means in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Marginalisation occurs in the context where you have a statement about the joint/conditional behaviour of a random variable $A$ and another random variable $B$.  To "marginalise" the second random variable out of the equation means that you remove it as a joint/conditioning variable.  This usually involves some kind of integration over the latter variable.

In your question it is unclear exactly how this is being done, since there is no mention of a variable $B$ in the cited portion of the material.  Nevertheless, in the case of marginalising a conditioning variable out of a variance you would usually use the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), which says that:

$$\mathbb{V}(A) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{V}(A|B)) + \mathbb{V}(\mathbb{E}(A|B)).$$